# Getting multiple column values at the same time in QGIS using Python

Tags: qgis, python, expression, qt, null

I need to filter multiple column values using python in QGIS. I am facing issue while writing expression using `QgisExpression(qgis.core)`.

If one of the column values is NULL then also I need to get the row. Is there a better solution to handle this or any other package to handle the expressions in QGIS?

You can see below an example to illustrate

```py
QgsExpression(f"input='{abc}' OR value='{def}'") # here abc = 1 and def = NULL
```

Comment: Can you give us an expression/code sample/excerpt you run and that do not work as you expect?

Comment: QgsExpression(f"input='{abc}' OR value='{def}'") here abc = 1 and def = NULL

Comment: Integrated your comment in the question. FYI, when giving precision, it's better to edit your answer as it's clearer for other reading your question than looking at a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manage NULL value by changing you expression to be able to manage when values are NULL. The syntax you use is not adapted as you don't compare NULL value with equal but with the syntax `yourfield IS NULL` OR `yourfield IS NOT NULL`.
I've also used `def1` instead of `def` as `def` is a reserved word in Python

```py
def1 = 'NULL'
valExp = f"value IS NULL" if def1 == 'NULL' else f"value='{def1}'"
exp = QgsExpression(f"input='{abc}' OR {valExp}")
```

Comment: The above expression is working fine. Is there a way to use AND here instead of OR. When i changed the OR to AND it failed to return the expected result and instead it resulted in NULL

Comment: What i need here is to get the row value based on both the conditions